# Chromium Embedded Framework CefSharp Initialisation error in Azure Web Job

Tags: azure, cefsharp

My organistaion have been using Chromium Embedded Framework with CefSharp

```
CefSharp.OffScreen.63.0.3
CefSharp.Common.63.0.3
cef.redist.x??.3.3239.1723
```

Until now it has been deployed as a service on a Windows Virtual Machine in MS Azure where it is used to capture screenshots and save to PDF. It has been working ok like this. But it is now required to reconfigue the application and deploy it as an Azure Web Job in its own App Service. After deployment to Azure, the Web App is started and begins initialisation. During this a call is made to Cef.Initialize() after which the following errors appear in the Web Job logs:

```
[04/23/2020 19:18:22 > ae786a: ERR ] [0423/171822.006:ERROR:network_change_notifier_win.cc(157)] WSALookupServiceBegin failed with: 5
[04/23/2020 19:18:22 > ae786a: ERR ] [0423/171822.131:ERROR:audio_device_listener_win.cc(45)] RegisterEndpointNotificationCallback failed: 80004005
```

I can find little to indicate what might be causing this to fail or how to resolve it. The Web Job is running in a dedicated App Service with a single instance. There are no problems when debugging locally in Visual Studio. But I am wondering whether there is something wrong with this configuration, or whether it is even possible to run Cef from within an Azure Web Job.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you able to test with the latest version of CefSharp?  At time of writing 79.1.360 there are no configuration options I can think of that would be relevant.

Comment: Likely CefSharp cannot run in a sandbox environment like App Service. https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/Azure-Web-App-sandbox

Comment: Thanks for replies. I think @CSharpRocks has identified the problem; we will need to devise another approach.